# Costly capital adjustment

Tags: capital

Why do we need to take FOC w.r.t both $K_t$ and $I_t$ in presence of costly capital adjustment when capital accumulation follows $  K_t = (1-\delta)K_{t-1} + \Biggl[1-S\left(\frac{I_t}{I_{t-1}}\right)\Biggr]I_t$

Comment: I guess this is because $I_t$ now becomes function of both $K_t$ and $I_{t-1}$, therefore it is not enough to know about $K_t$.